# Implement CompareTo() - compare by various functions

Tags: c#, compare, compareto

I implemented `CompareTo()` like so:

```
 public override int CompareTo(object obj)
 {
   //quick failsafe
   MyClass other;
   if (obj is MyClass)
   {
     other = obj as MyClass;
   }
   else 
   { 
     return 1; 
   }
   //now we should have another comparable object.
   /*
    * 1: this is greater.
    * 0: equals.
    * -1: this is less.  
    */
   if (other.GetValue() < this.GetValue())
   {
     // this is bigger
     return 1;
   }
   else if (other.GetValue() > this.GetValue())
   {
     //this is smaller
     return -1;
   }
   else 
   { 
     return 0; 
   }
}
```

However, things get interesting when I want to chose the function `GetValue()`. I have a couple of them set up for that: namely `Average()`, `Best()`, `CorrectedAverage()`, `Median()`. I compare by an array of `floats` by the way. Thing is, I don't want to use a `switch-case` on an `enum` I defined in this class to tell what to order by. Is there a way that I decide which function to order by nice and clean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that your class has a whole bunch of different ways of comparing it, it almost certainly *shouldn't implement `IComparable` at all*.

Instead, create `IComparer<T>` instances for each different way of comparing your object.  Someone who wants to comparer instances of the type can then pick the comparer that uses the comparison that's most appropriate for their situation.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have a hinch what you mean, but could you explain a bit further? I mean, how to do it?

Comment: @hei You create a class that implements `IComparer<T>` for each way you have to compare your object.  Each object compares them a different way.  Someone wishing to perform an operation that requires knowing how these objects are compared (for example, a sort operation) can accept the comparer appropriate to the situation.  If they want to compare using the median, they use the `MedianComparer`, if they want to compare using the mean, they use the `MeanComparer`, and so on.

Comment: So I have like 4 "CompareTo()" functions? And I more or less copy-paste, just use different functions instead of `GetValue()`

Comment: @hei You wouldn't be copy-pasting.  Almost none of the function would overlap.  Having `return firstArray.Median().CompareTo(second.Median());` doesn't really have enough overlap with other options to really need to copy-paste.  The functions are more different than they are the same, even if they'd have a similar structure.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I go and implement it.